# Switching src in existing Iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am very very new to JavaScript and have been trying to solve how to change the source for an iframe, the issue is the iframe is rendered via a script so I can't add a `class`/`id`.

```
<ul>
  <li><a onClick="na()">NA/EU</a></li>
  <li><a>LCK</a></li>
  <li><a>LPL</a></li>
  <li><a>LMS</a></li>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function na() {
    document.getElementsByTagName("iframe").setAttribute('src', 'http://player.twitch.tv/?allowfullscreen&channel=riotgames&video=%3Cvideo%20ID%3E&collection=%3Ccollection%20ID%3E&origin=file%3A%2F%2F');
  }
</script>
<div class="container" id="first-container">
  <row>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <script src="http://player.twitch.tv/js/embed/v1.js"></script>
      <div id="<player div ID>"></div>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        var options = {
          width: "100%",
          height: "720",
          channel: "faker",
          video: "<video ID>",
          collection: "<collection ID>",
        };
        var player = new Twitch.Player("<player div ID>", options);
        player.setVolume(0.5);
      </script>
    </div>
    <div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you select element by tag name it returns all matching elements.

From W3School website:

> The getElementsByTagName() method returns a collection of all elements in the document with the specified tag name, as a NodeList object.
>
> The NodeList object represents a collection of nodes. The nodes can be accessed by index numbers. The index starts at 0.

So instead of doing `document.getElementsByTagName("iframe").setAttribute('src', 'http://player.twitch.tv/?allowfullscreen&channel=riotgames&video=%3Cvideo%20ID%3E&collection=%3Ccollection%20ID%3E&origin=file%3A%2F%2F');`

you need to do `document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].setAttribute('src', 'http://player.twitch.tv/?allowfullscreen&channel=riotgames&video=%3Cvideo%20ID%3E&collection=%3Ccollection%20ID%3E&origin=file%3A%2F%2F');`

Here is [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BPJYMj) for it.

And yes don't forget that it will change the `src` of first `iframe` node in the document.